# No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5112/Clients/Create

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core-webapi, crud

I am Building a CRUD Operations using ASP.NET Core Web Application With SQL Server Database Connection. The View "http://localhost:5112/Clients" link is working. I am facing this error issue "No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5112/Clients/Create" I can fetch the record stored in the database but when selecting the Create page the the error is shown showing the webpage was not found I am attaching the codes please help me out.

below is the view record page code

Index.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyStore.Pages.Clients
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<ClientInfo> listClients = new List<ClientInfo>(); 
        public void OnGet()
        {
            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mystore;Integrated Security=True";

                using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM clients";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            { 
                                ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
                                clientInfo.id = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                                clientInfo.name = reader.GetString(1);
                                clientInfo.email = reader.GetString(2);
                                clientInfo.phone = reader.GetString(3);
                                clientInfo.address = reader.GetString(4);
                                clientInfo.created_at = reader.GetDateTime(5).ToString();

                                listClients.Add(clientInfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClientInfo
    {
        public String id;
        public String name;
        public String email;
        public String phone;
        public String address;
        public String created_at;
    }

}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model MyStore.Pages.Clients.IndexModel
@{
}

<br>
<h2>List of Clients</h2>
<a class ='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href ='/Clients/Create'>New Client</a>
<table class= "table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.listClients)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.id</td>
                <td>@item.name</td>
                <td>@item.email</td>
                <td>@item.phone</td>
                <td>@item.address</td>
                <td>@item.created_at</td>

                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Clients/Edit?id=@item.id">Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="/Clients/delete?id=@item.id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

now attaching the create page

Create.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 

namespace MyStore.Pages.Clients
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        public ClientInfo ClientInfo = new ClientInfo();
        public String errorMessage = "";
        public String successMessage = "";
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }


        public void OnPost()
        {
            ClientInfo.name = Request.Form["name"];
            ClientInfo.email = Request.Form["email"];
            ClientInfo.phone = Request.Form["phone"];
            ClientInfo.address = Request.Form["address"];

            if(ClientInfo.name.Length == 0 || ClientInfo.email.Length == 0 || ClientInfo.phone.Length == 0 || ClientInfo.address.Length == 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "All the Fields are required!";
                return;
            }

            //save the new client into the database

            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mystore;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = " INSERT INTO clients " + " (name, email, phone, address) VALUES " + "(@name, @email, @phone, @address);";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ClientInfo.name);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", ClientInfo.email);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone",ClientInfo.phone);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", ClientInfo.address);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
                return;
            }


            ClientInfo.name = ""; ClientInfo.email = ""; ClientInfo.phone = ""; ClientInfo.address = "";
            successMessage = "New Client added Correctly";

            Response.Redirect("/Clients/Index");
        }    
    }
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
@page
@model MyStore.Pages.Clients.CreateModel
@{
}

<br>
<h2>New Client</h2>

@if(Model.errorMessage.Length>0)
{
    <div class= 'alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show' role ='alert'>
        <strong>@Model.errorMessage</strong>
        <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dissmiss='alert' aria-label='close'></button>
    </div>
}

<form method="POST">
    <div class ="row mb-3">
        <label class ="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="@Model.ClientInfo.name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="@Model.ClientInfo.email">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="@Model.ClientInfo.phone">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="@Model.ClientInfo.address">
        </div>
    </div>

    @if(Model.successMessage.Length>0)
    {
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>
                    <strong>@Model.successMessage</strong>
                    <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

   <div class="row mb-3">
       <div class ="offset-sm-3 col-sm-3 d-grid">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3 d-grid">
           <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/" role="button">Cancel</a>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

I tried renaming the pages but didn't worked

Comment: In which folder are the two cshtml pages located? Relative from the root site.

Comment: Client folder under Pages folder

Comment: I would try to remove the first / from /Clients/Create href or else add a ~ in fron of the /Clients/Create. However I find your setup a bit unusual. I prefer to have areas for a set of related pages about a specific function

Comment: I tried Steve neither worked

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you can launch the specific page from visual studio and it should show you the Url to the page. So if you are on the "Create" Client view and click run I should open the browser to that page.

Comment: I tried your code in my side and it didn't reproduce the issue. Do you have any route configurations in `Program.cs`? By the way, I think you can set a route in the `create.cshtml`. Change `@page` to `@page "~/Clients/Create"`

Comment: Tried ur suggestion tiny wang but it is not working out for me

Comment: could you pls show us your program.cs?   in the meantime, could you pls go to the project folder and delete the `bin` and `obj` folders and then test again?

Comment: tiny i have attached the program.cs code please check

Comment: thank you for your response. and it's obvious that you didn't have any role influencing the routing in your Program.cs.... I just want to double confirm with you that, have you tried to `create a new empty asp.net core web app` and add Clients folder, then in this folder added new Razor Page named  Create, then test if it worked for you? I'm sorry I can't reproduce your issue and your code looks good.

Comment: i got the problem solved buddy thanks for efforts though

Comment: I'm glad to see it, and could you pls let us know how you solved the issue? you may post as the answer

Comment: I had two problems in full crud project one was the create problem and other was that the update was able to get the data from the data base but not able to post it again after changes so found the error and it was the query problem spacing was not done properly and 2nd problem was with create so I had mistakenly used another page to code the create so I copied the code and then deleted the page and added a new razor empty page and pasted the code.